# Inheritance in case classes

Tags: scala

I have the following case class definition:

```
case class FileMetadata(announceUrls: List[String], pieceLength: Int, pieces: String) {
  case class SingleFileMetadata(filename: String, length: Int)
  case class MultiFileMetadata(dirname: String, files: List[FileInfo])
}
```

because I want both the single and multi file types to have all the same data values as the enclosing `FileMetaData` case class. This doesn't really seem to work though (in that I can't create a new `SingleFileMetadata` or `MultiFileMetaData` class.

Is there a way to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code, `SingleFileMetadata` and `MultiFileMetadata` *do not* inherit from `FileMetadata`. In fact, they *only* exist within specific instances of `FileMetadata`, which you most certainly do not want. Furthermore, you cannot extend a case class, as all of the members are private, so `FileMetadata` would have to be a class (or trait).

Something like this might work for you:

```
class FileMetadata(announceUrls: List[String], pieceLength: Int, pieces: String)

case class SingleFileMetadata(filename: String, length: Int, announceUrls: List[String], pieceLength: Int, pieces: String) extends FileMetadata(announceUrls, pieceLength, pieces)

case class MultiFileMetadata(dirname: String, files: List[FileInfo], announceUrls: List[String], pieceLength: Int, pieces: String) extends FileMetadata(announceUrls, pieceLength, pieces)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make your base class a trait and make both case classes inherit from it.

```
trait FileMetadata {
  def announceUrls: List[String]
  def pieceLength: Int 
  def pieces: String
}

case class SingleFileMetadata(filename: String, length: Int, announceUrls: List[String], pieceLength: Int, pieces: String) extends FileMetadata
case class MultiFileMetadata(dirname: String, files: List[FileInfo], announceUrls: List[String], pieceLength: Int, pieces: String) extends FileMetadata
```

One additional advantage of using trait is that you can limit the inheritance to only the classes defined in the given file, by specifying that `trait` as a `sealed trait`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to your problem would be to create only one generic case class, set optional parameters to default value None, with flexible pattern matching you can easily perform operation on this class.

```
case class GenericFileMetadata(filename:Option[String] = None,
                               length:Option[String] = None,
                               dirname:Option[String] = None,
                               files:Option[List[FileInfo]]= None,
                               announceUrls: List[String], pieceLength: Int, pieces: String)
```